# Tortoise SVN Error (405 Method Not Allowed) When checking out from CodePlex

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, codeplex, svn-checkout

I have just created a new project in CodePlex (Subversion Source Control), checked out a folder on my PC and tried to commit the initial files (27MB). The commit was not successful due to accidental internet disconnection on my part.

When I tried to re-commit the files, I got Error 405: `(Server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed) in response to PROPFIND request for '/'`

So I deleted the project and recreated it hoping the problem goes away, but now I can't even do the initial checkout to add files for commit. If I create a project with another name, I have no problem in checking out/committing.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this behaviour or should I just wait and hope the problem goes away?

Answer (score -1):

I used commandline sliksvn from http://www.sliksvn.com/, and discovered conflicts between the server and the local sandbox, I selected "mf" from the selection prompt as shown below and the problem was fixed:

Select: (p) postpone,
        (mf) mine-full, (tf) theirs-full,
        (s) show all options: mf

Comment: What answer is this? Seems unrelated to the question.

Comment: The answer is completely unrelated to the question.